# Unidirectional vs Bi-directional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a basic diary project and a one to many relationship with two entities, User and DiaryEntry. The problem is I have two ways to add data, one being bi-directional and the other uni. The trouble with the bi-directional approach is that I can not get the id off the diary object recently added to the database to send to the user but I am not sure how important this actually is. The other approach is to use a uni directional which allows me to get the diary object added directly and return it to the user but most advice online is to use bi-directional approaches. Any advice appreciated as I am just trying to get familiar with the best approaches to spring rest apps.

```
public void createDiaryEntryNoResult(Long uId, DiaryEntryDTO diaryEntryDTO) {

         userRepository.findById(uId)
                .map(user -> {
                    DiaryEntry diaryEntry = 
         diaryEntryMapper.diaryEntryDTOToDiaryEntry(diaryEntryDTO);
                    user.addDiaryEntry(diaryEntry);
                    userRepository.save(user);
                    return user;
                })
                .orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);

}
```

```
public DiaryEntryDTO createDiaryEntryWithResult(Long uId, DiaryEntryDTO diaryEntryDTO) {

        DiaryEntry diaryEntry = diaryEntryMapper.diaryEntryDTOToDiaryEntry(diaryEntryDTO);
        User user = userRepository.findById(uId).orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);
        diaryEntry.setUser(user);
        DiaryEntry savedDiaryEntry = diaryEntryRepository.save(diaryEntry);
        return diaryEntryMapper.diaryEntryToDiaryEntryDTO(savedDiaryEntry);
}
```

Comment: also random thing but 'bidirectional' an 'unidirectional' are not the right terms used for describing this dilemma, the problem is whether or not you're returning response or returning empty body in your request. People may confuse this with defining entity relationships as bi and uni directional which totally different thing. So you might want to change the title of the question...

Comment: I will try and reword it a bit but it is the right terms because the second method is based on the entity relatioinship being changed to a uni-directional on and changing the way the data is saved. So it's sort of a two part problem.

Answer (score 1):

"The trouble with the bi-directional approach is that I can not get the id off the diary object recently added to the database to send to the user but I am not sure how important this actually is."

The id should be present in savedDiaryEntry after calling save method...

There is no "correct" approach - it depends on the person using the API.

Do they need the id in the response at that moment or is it for information purpose only? If for some reason you need that id to call some other API methods then correct approach would be of course to return the id in the response otherwise it's ok to return no content.

If they don't need the id at the moment then returning only "200 OK" or "201 No content" response with no body is correct approach, it all depends on what the person calling the API will need at the time or what's more convenient for them...

Comment: I should have said I can't get the reference to the object recently added. I can get the User that it's been added to from the save() but the actual diaryEntry goes into a Set or List inside the User entity and I'm not sure how to access it as it gets saved. But to answer the other question the client is also me and I don't need the object/id as it was just to comply with standards and the other save features of the API wich return what was saved.

Comment: ao are you saying that at this line:         DiaryEntry savedDiaryEntry = diaryEntryRepository.save(diaryEntry), savedDiaryEntry doesn't have id field populated?

Comment: no it does in that method, but the first method that saves the diary entry by using the userRepository only returns the user entity which contains the list of diaryEntry objects but from this i have no way of identifying what one was recently added apart from iterating the list to the last item but I feel that in production that would no guarentee it being the most recent diaryEtnry added to the user. The User entity has a bi-directional data set of DiaryEntry objects associated with it. Which is why issuse is the top method saves it with one query which is probably ideal, but the other return

Comment: There is not absolutely correct approach to do this and I think your code does not have any issue. It also depends how do you use two methods, if I need to the provide the whole `User` response, I would use the first method and if I have to return only added Diary entry, I will use second method.